# Find posterior distribution and Bayes estimator

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, bayesian

Suppose that an observation $x \in (-1,1)$  comes from a sample model with a parameter $\theta$, with density function:

$$
f(x\mid\theta) = \begin{cases}
 \theta\ if -1 < x < 0\\
      1 - \theta\ if\ 0 \leqslant x < 1
\end{cases}\
$$

a) Suppose that the prior distribution for $\theta$ is uniform over the interval $(0,1)$.
Find a Bayes estimator associated with this priori distribution, under the quadratic loss function.

I think for this question, we need to find $E(\theta\mid x)$; here is what I got:

$$
f(\theta\mid x) = \begin{cases}
 \theta\ if -1 < x < 0\\
      1 - \theta\ if\ 0 \leqslant x < 1
\end{cases}\
$$
since the prior distribution is $\pi (\theta) = 1$. But I'm unsure how to continue.

Comment: Your posterior expression for $f(\theta \mid x)$ integrates over $\theta$ to $\frac12$ in both cases ($x$ positive or negative) when as a density it should integrate to $1$.  So you may have missed a step.  Once that is corrected, you can find $E[\theta \mid x]$ for each case as you would with other densities

Comment: So I'm wondering with a $f(x \mid\theta)$ defined on many intervals like this one, how can we compute the posterior distribution correctly?

Comment: Slightly changing the notation to reduce ambiguity, so the prior distribution is $\pi(\theta)$ and the posterior distribution $\pi(\theta \mid x)$ and using $\phi$ as alternative to $\theta$, you should have $\pi(\theta \mid x) = \frac{\pi(\theta) \,f(x \mid \theta)}{\int \pi(\phi) \,f(x \mid \phi)\, d\phi}$.  Find this when $x$ is positive and when $x$ is negative.  Then find $E[\theta \mid x] =  \int \theta \,\pi(\theta \mid x)\, d\theta$ when $x$ is positive and when $x$ is negative.

Comment: I know the formula but don't understand how to get the correct distribution. So basically, we will calculate $\pi(\theta \mid x)$ separately for $x$ positive and negative? For the first case where $x$ is positive: $$\pi(\theta \mid x) = \frac{\theta} { 1} = \theta$$? Can you pls show me which is wrong in my calculations?

Comment: The $1$ in the denominator is wrong. Hence my two previous comments

Comment: Can you please show my how to calculate the denominator? I calculated the integral over $\phi$ and $\phi$ goes from $0-1$ and $f(x \mid \phi) = \phi$. Isn't it?

Comment: $\int\limits_0^1 x \, dx =\frac{x^2}2 \Big|_0^1=\frac12$ not $1$ and you can replace $x$ by $\theta$ or $\phi$

Comment: Hi Henry, does that mean: $$
f(\theta\mid x) = \begin{cases}
2 \theta\ if -1 < x < 0\\
      2(1 - \theta\) if\ 0 \leqslant x < 1
\end{cases}\
$$
and $E(\theta\mid x) = 2\theta P(-1 < x < 0) + 2(1-\theta) P(0 \leqslant x < 1)$

Comment: Your $f(\theta \mid x)$ looks correct now, but your $E[\theta \mid x]$ does not as it should not include $\theta$ (you are trying to estimate $\theta)$.  You should be getting $\frac23$ or $\frac13$, depending on the sign of $x$

Comment: Oh right, I think I understand now. So, we always separate the problem in 2 cases (x negative and x positive). So we'll receive two Bayes estimators depending on which case we are considering.

Comment: Yes - if you are trying to be clever, you could try writing write something like $\frac12+\frac16\mathrm{sign}(x)$, but it is clearer when you just treat it as two cases and you also deal correctly with the possibility $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!